# Jenkins Jelly Updating Textbox

Tags: java, jenkins, textbox, jelly

Is it possible to dynamically update a textbox's value in Jelly?

I have a drop-down box whose options are determined based on previous data in the form. Accomplishing that was straightforward with the documentation available online (simply using the `doFill...Items()` method in the descriptor). Each option represents a `"Property"`. Under the drop-down, I have a textbox, which represents the Property's `"Property Value"`.

Jelly File:

```
<j:jelly xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:st="jelly:stapler" xmlns:d="jelly:define" xmlns:l="/lib/layout" xmlns:t="/lib/hudson" xmlns:f="/lib/form">
    <f:entry title="Property" field="property">
        <f:select />
    </f:entry>
    <f:entry title="Value" field="propertyValue">
        <f:textbox value="${descriptor.getDefaultValue()}" />
    </f:entry>
    <div align="right">
        <f:repeatableDeleteButton/>
    </div>
</j:jelly>
```

Each time a new item in the drop-down box is selected, I want to update the textbox with the Property's current value. I've been trying a handful of different things, such as setting the `default` and `value` attributes in the Jelly file. However, I have not been able to figure out a way to trigger an update to the textbox after the form has been initialized.

Descriptor:

```
@Extension
public static class DescriptorImpl extends Descriptor<ProvisionPropertyParam> {
    /**
     * Gets a list of update properties for a specific component.
     *
     * @param component
     * @return ListBoxModel - the list of update properties for the component
     */
    public ListBoxModel doFillPropertyItems(@QueryParameter("component") @RelativePath("..") String component) {
        return ServiceManager.userInterfaceService().getProvisionProperties(component);
    }
    public String doFillPropertyValue(@QueryParameter("property") String property) {
        return ServiceManager.userInterfaceService().getPropertyValue(property);
    }
    public String getDefaultValue() {
        return "Test";
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public String getDisplayName() {
        return "Provision property";
    }
}
```

I am able to set the value of the textbox with the `getDefaultValue()` method successfully. However, I need to be able to use the `doFillPropertyValue()`, or some differently named method which operates the same way. I would imagine it should be as simple as setting the method in the jelly file, but the method in question has a parameter, and I am unsure how to make the method call in the jelly, considering I don't have a value to send it.

I tried setting:

```
<f:textbox value="${descriptor.doFillPropertyValue()}"/>
```

But it obviously didn't do anything. Can anyone provide me with some guidance?

Comment: Have you tried without parenthensis at the end?

Answer (score 0):

In my jelly code I use something like this :

```
    <j:forEach var="currentDescriptor" items="${descriptor.tilogiPlateformeDescriptors}" varStatus="loop">
```

And in my java code the method is :

```
    public DescriptorExtensionList<TilogiPlateforme, TilogiPlateformeDescriptor> getTilogiPlateformeDescriptors()
```

Answer (score 0):

`doFill{Variable}Items` method is called when you refresh the page or when you enter the page by using Configure option. So its static method called once for page.

Jelly Pages supports HTML and Javascript. For drop down box you can use `onfocus` or `onclick` method as `onfocus = "populateTextbox()"`.

Use simple java script as

```
select = document.getElementById("Id of DropDown");
selectedData = select.options.selected.text
```

Update the text box with `selectedData` value